# Use Uitapgesture recognizer on multiple image views that are not declared

Tags: swift, append, uitapgesturerecognizer, func, undeclared-identifier

My swift code uses func addBox to add and append image views to the uiview controller. All I want to do is when one of the image views are tapped is for func viewClicked to be activated. Right now nothing is happening and nothing is being written into the debug area.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


var ht = -90
var ww = 80
var hw = 80
var arrTextFields = [UIImageView]()
var b7 = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    [b7].forEach {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview($0)
        $0.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
    }

    b7.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y + 200, width: 70, height: 40)
    b7.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addBOx), for: .touchUpInside)
   for view in self.arrTextFields {
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewClicked)))
    }
}



@objc func viewClicked(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   print("tap")
}


//func that adds imageview.
@objc func addBOx() {

    let subview = UIImageView()

    subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    arrTextFields.append(subview)
    view.addSubview(subview)

    subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 0, y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(ht), width: CGFloat(ww), height: 35)


    subview.backgroundColor = .purple

    ht += 50
    arrTextFields.append(subview)




}
}
```

Comment: no need for `as [UIImageView] `

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable user interation

```
for view in self.arrTextFields {
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewClicked)))
}
```

---

```
@objc func viewClicked(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   print("tap")
}
```

Comment: changed my code above with your suggestion. Still having no effect and nothing is being printed.

Comment: Do you add the images to the view ??

Comment: If I take away the brackets from [UIImageView](), I get compile errors.